# Best practice for displaying items in localStorage in html.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, local-storage

I have an array of items in localStorage that I want to display in my index.html.erb file. I'm using rails for this application. Should I send the information to my rails controller and then send it to my index.html.erb or is there a way to do it without sending the info to the controller? I rather not save the information on the server side.

Here's my code in my index.html.erb

```
<div>
  <div id="result">
  <script>
    function storage(){
      var items =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cars"))
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = items[i]
      }
    }
    storage()
  </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now this is showing just one item in the array in the view page instead of a number of items. If I do have to send the information to the controller first, how would I go about doing that? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the html every iteration so only the last item will be shown

Try something like:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += (items[i] + '<br>`);
```

---

Note: This assumes you are actually storing an array

Comment: Given that you can restructure the html to be more semantic as needed